# Python remove lowest value

Tags: python, pseudocode

This is my pseudo code that i have to translate into python

```
A=99
LENGTH= LENGTH(list)
LIST= 92 50 26 82 73 
for P in range 0 to LENGTH-1
    IF LIST[P] <A THEN
        A=LIST[P]
        B=P
    ENDIF
ENDFOR
IF B < LENGTH THEN
    for P in range B to LENGTH -2
        LIST[P] = LIST[P+1]
    ENDFOR
ENDIF
LENGTH=LENGTH-1
LIST[LENGTH]=NULL
```

My attempt at coding done below, the code is meant to remove the lowest value from the LIST

```
a = 99
list=[92,50,26,82,73]

for  p in  range  (0,len(list) - 1):
    if list[p] < a :
        a = list[p] 
        b = p 

print (list) #I just added this to see what was happening

if  b < len(list):
    for p in range (b,len(list)-2):
        list[p]=list[p]+1

list=len(list)-1

print (list)
#I just added this to see what was happening
```

I have wrote the code above and it doesnt remove the lowest value

Comment: have you tried [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) or [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) method? Also, `list` is a keyword in python, good practice to use a different variable name

Comment: a = 99
list=[92,50,26,82,73]
length=len(list)
for  p in  range  (0,length ):
    if list[p] < a :
        a = list[p] #a=92
        b = p #b=0

print (list)

if  b < length:
    for p in range (b, length-2):
        list[p]=list[p+1]
        print(list)
length=length-1
del list[length]
print(list)

Comment: see answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really close, here are the corrections:

```
A = 99

l = [92, 50, 26, 82, 73]

LENGTH = len(l)

for P in range(LENGTH):
    if l[P] < A:
        A=l[P]
        B=P

if B < LENGTH:
    for P in range (B, LENGTH - 1):
        l[P] = l[P+1]


LENGTH=LENGTH-1
l[LENGTH]=None
```

Now try:

```
print(l) # [92, 50, 82, 73, None]
```

Note:
`LENGTH-1` and `LENGTH-2` are changed to `LENGTH` and `LENGTH-1` because Python uses 0-based indexing.

Answer (score 0):

- first list is a bad variable name. it already has meaning in python.
- to iterate over list items just do

```
for item in items:
    # use item.
```

- if you want the index as well

```
for idx in range(len(items)):   # no need for -1
    # use items[idx]
```

- your soln

```
minval = min(items)
new_items = []
for item in items:
    if item != minval:
        new_items.append(item)

# new items has the answer
```